# What does assignment to *this do (*this = val)?

Tags: c++, qt, this

I was browsing Qt sources, and noticed this

```
QUuid &operator=(const GUID &guid)
{
    *this = QUuid(guid);
    return *this;
}
```

I've never seen assignment to "this" before. What does assignment to "this" do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is not an assignment to `this` but to the object pointed by `this`. That will effectively call `operator=( QUuid const & )` on the current object.

Comment: or the implicit one (if no assignment operator is defined)

Comment: @smerlin: Whether the operator is explicitly defined by the user or implicitly defined by the compiler is more of an implementation detail, it is the same operator.

Comment: BTW, the code `*this = QUuid(guid);` is equivalent to the more explicit and cumbersome: `this->operator=( QUuid(guid) )`... not that this affects the answer in any way.

Answer (score 4):

It just invokes `QUuid &operator=(const QUuid& quUid);`.

Answer (score 1):

'this' is simply a pointer to the object on which the current method is invoked. Changing the value  behind 'this' (by dereferencing the pointer using '*this' and assigning another object) modifies the caller's object to become another one.

In your example, a caller of 'operator=' might do the following:

```
GUID guid = guid(...) ;
QUuid uid = guid ;
```

According to the definition of 'operator=' this action copy-converts 'guid' into a new object of type 'QUuid'.