# Does it make sense to modify an object as a whole using one of its behavior? Say inside the assignment operator overloading using this pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, object

I see a question on this operator ([What does assignment to *this do (*this = val)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734241/what-does-assignment-to-this-do-this-val))

but is it logical to modify an object as a whole from within one of its behavior? Does it makes sense in OOP world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense when it makes sense from a design perspective.  I'd expect `Rect`, `Size` and `Point` classes, for example, to support assignment.  In this sense, these kinds of types (to me) should behave like plain-old-datatypes (PODs).

But if I was modelling a traffic simulation with cars and trucks, I certainly would not have an assignment operator.  Setting one car to equal another just doesn't make any sense.  I might `clone` a car (Make a new one that looks just like the another one), but once a car is created it will always be *that* car.  It can't *become* another kind of car.

As a further example, consider a `Person` object:

```
class Person
{
private:
    std::string m_Name;
};
```

Would you expect a `Person` to have an assignment operator?  No.  A Person cannot *become* another person.  However, what about his name?  Sure!  A Person can change his name, so an assignment operator on the name makes perfect sense.

So to answer your question, it makes sense to do it where it makes sense to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

it completely depends on the logic of your code. by modifying object "as a whole" you're sure that you don't brake its invariants. usually if class provide operator= nothing wrong to use it.

in referred questions it's pretty logical way to call overloaded assignment operator, so it's a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes sense in OOP, but C++ isn't pure OOP, it's a multi paradigm language and in order to correctly use C++ you must understand it, not OOP or other paradigms.

A member function, in C++, is just a function whit an *implicit* `this` parameter. (A function member of class `A` has got an `A *this` *implicit* parameter.) Then it *implicitly* passes `this` to the other functions in the same class.

A function can then use `this` as it wants to, and this makes sense in C++.

Comment: I think he just wanted to discuss the reality of assigning one thing to another, rather than the semantics of dereferencing `this`. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I'm not sure. I thought he wanted to discuss the assignment of one thing to another specifically within a method of the latter.

Comment: @Troubadour, I can understand how the question might be a bit misleading, but when I saw "Does it makes sense in OOP world?" I thought it was more to do with *theory* of assigning rather than the language semantics.  I may, of course, be completely wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

The example given in the question you linked to is simply defining an assignment operator in terms of another one i.e. it allows one to assign a `GUID` to a `QUuid` and does so by simply constructing a `QUuid` and the using the "regular" assigment operator for `QUuid` that takes another `QUuid` as an argument.

So, yes, it makes perfect sense. One would expect an assignment operator to change the whole instance. For other member functions, unless they are appropriately named to suggest that they are performing a function similar to assignment, I would not expect to see `*this =`.